# Cookie cutting in R?

Tags: qgis, r, intersection

Is it possible to perform a cookie cut in R?

Firstly, I have a polygon shapefile of many polygon some of which overlap. I then have a second polygon shapefile with contiguous non-overlapping polygons. I want to establish the parts of the first (potentially overlapping) polygons that fall within each of the second (non-overlapping) polygons. The first shapefile is a number of layers of cookie dough to cut and the second is the cutter to apply. Alternatively I can use QGIS if people think that's the best way to go.

Comment: Have you looked at the operations on polygons provided by the `sf` package? In particular `st_difference` might be the one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution in R:

```
library(rgeos)
library(rgdal)
dough <- readOGR("poly1.shp")
cutter <- readOGR("poly2.shp")
cookies <- gIntersection(dough, cutter, byid=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks Micha, looks so elegant that it must be true. I'll try this later in the week and hopefully come back with a tick.

Comment: Note this uses `sp` classes for spatial data - a solution with `sf` classes should always be preferred, which would use `st_intersection`

Comment: I have the following class for my spatial data, so I think I'm good to go.
> class(iso)
[1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"